# Javascript in C# Listener if condition

Tags: javascript, c#, extjs, ext.net

I have this combobox:

```
<ext:ComboBox ID="PhonePrefix" runat="server" Width="470" Editable="false" FieldLabel="Phone prefix" Mode="Local" AllowBlank=false  HideTrigger="true" EmptyText="Country">
      <Items>
           <ext:ListItem Text="Greece (+30)" Value="+30"  />
           <ext:ListItem Text="France (+33)" Value="+33" />
           <ext:ListItem Text="Germany (+49)" Value="+49" />
           <ext:ListItem Text="Italy (+39)" Value="+39" />
           <ext:ListItem Text="Jordan (+962)" Value="+962" />
           <ext:ListItem Text="Lebanon (+961)" Value="+961" />
           <ext:ListItem Text="Saudi Arabia (+966)" Value="+966" />
           <ext:ListItem Text="United Kingdom (+44)" Value="+44" />  
           <ext:ListItem Text="United States (+1)" Value="+1" />     
      </Items>
      <SelectedItems>
           <ext:ListItem Index="0" />
      </SelectedItems>  
      <Listeners>
         <Change Handler="if(this.value.length == 4)
                               #{txtSiteAddDoctorMobile}.minLength = 9;
                        //else
                             //#{txtSiteAddDoctorMobile}.minLength = 10;
          " />
      </Listeners>   
</ext:ComboBox>
```

With the listener I want to change the minLength of the textfield. Like this the code works but when I uncomment the `else` statement then I get js errors:

> a.getData is not a function
>
> Cannot set property 'minLength' of undefined
>
> l.getCount is not a function
>
> Cannot read property 'dom' of undefined

Comment: probably because that code doesn't appear to be valid Javascript

Comment: Is "txtSiteAddDoctorMobile" present on the page? TextField doesn't have minLength property. Use setMaxLength() instead.

Comment: can you add "txtSiteAddDoctorMobile" details please?